# Data info inside of modal

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I need to show info which is in DB inside of modal, when the user made click in the button of each offer the modal shows the offer with that id... the problem is the modal info is empty...so how can I catch the id to show the proper data into the modal?

Here is the offer:

```
<?php if($spa_style == basico) { echo '
    <div class="row">';
            $sql = "SELECT id_oferta, oferta_titulo, oferta_subtitulo, oferta_mensaje, oferta_precio, estado, oferta_foto, style, cupon, popular FROM SPA_OFERTAS WHERE estado = 'activado' ORDER BY id_oferta DESC LIMIT 4";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  if (!empty($id_oferta)) { echo '
        <div class="span3" id"'.$row["id_oferta"].'">
            <div class="tile '.$row["popular"].'">
                <div>
                    <img src="img/ofertas/'.$row["oferta_foto"].'" alt="'.$row["oferta_titulo"].'" class="img-rounded img-left" style="width:70px; height:70px;" />
                </div>
                <span>'.$row["oferta_titulo"].'</span>
                <h6><small>'.$row["oferta_subtitulo"].'</small></h6>
                <p>'.$row["oferta_mensaje"].'</p>';
                if($row["cupon"] == si) {  echo '<h5><div class="intro-icon-disc"><a href="#spaferta" data-id="'.$row['id_oferta'].'" data-toggle="modal" role="button" class="open-SpaOferta btn btn-info"><b>$'.$row["oferta_precio"].'</b></a></div></h5>'; } 
else if($row["cupon"] == no) { echo '<br />'; } echo '
            </div>
            <div class="pad25"></div>
        </div>'; }  } echo '
    </div>'; } 
?>
```

Here the modal:

```
<?php 
    require_once('connection.php');
    $query = "SELECT id_oferta, oferta_titulo, oferta_subtitulo, oferta_mensaje, oferta_precio, oferta_foto FROM SPA_OFERTAS WHERE id_oferta = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_REQUEST['id_oferta']);    
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $id_oferta = $row['id_oferta'];
    $oferta_titulo = $row['oferta_titulo'];
    $oferta_subtitulo = $row['oferta_subtitulo'];
    $oferta_mensaje = $row['oferta_mensaje'];
    $oferta_precio = $row['oferta_precio'];
    $oferta_foto = $row['oferta_foto'];
 ?>
<div id="spaferta" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        <h3>Cup&oacute;n para : <?php echo $oferta_titulo; ?></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="message2"></div><br /><div id="Info_spa"></div>
        <form method="post" action="includes/spa_cupon.php" name="spaform" id="spaform">
            <div class="row-fluid grid">
                <div class="span6">
                    <label for="nombres" accesskey="U"><span class="required">*</span> <b>Nombres : </b></label><input type="text" class="input-block-level" id="nombres" name="nombres" />
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <label for="dui" accesskey="P"><span class="required">*</span> <b>DUI : </b></label><input type="text" class="input-block-level" id="spa_dui" name="dui" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid grid">
                <div class="span6">
                    <label for="corelectronico" accesskey="E"><span class="required">*</span> <b>Correo : </b></label><input type="email" class="input-block-level" id="corelectronico" name="corelectronico" />
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <label for="tele" accesskey="P"><span class="required">*</span> <b>Tel&eacute;fono/Celular : </b></label><input type="text" class="input-block-level" id="tele" name="tele" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid grid">
                <input type="hidden" id="of_titulo" name="of_titulo" type="text" value="<?php echo $oferta_titulo; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" id="of_stitulo" name="of_stitulo" type="text" value="<?php echo $oferta_subtitulo; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" id="of_mensaje" name="of_mensaje" type="text" value="<?php echo $oferta_mensaje; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" id="of_precio" name="of_precio" type="text" value="<?php echo $oferta_precio; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" id="of_foto" name="of_foto" type="text" value="<?php echo $oferta_foto; ?>" />
                <p><span class="required">*</span> Eres humano?</p>
                <label for="verify2" accesskey="V">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;7 - 5 =</label>
                <input name="verify2" type="text" id="verify2" size="4" value="" style="width: 30px;" /><br /><br />
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit" id="submit2" value="Grabar Cup&oacute;n" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
            Cerrar
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did u check the vars before populating the modal does your query come back with any data ?

Comment: the "data-id" in the `<a href="#spaferta" data-id="'.$row['id_oferta'].'" data-toggle="modal" role="button" class="open-SpaOferta btn btn-info"><b>$'.$row["oferta_precio"].'</b></a>` has the id number (id_oferta) of the offer...but I don't know how insert the data-id into the `$query = "SELECT id_oferta, oferta_titulo, oferta_subtitulo, oferta_mensaje, oferta_precio, oferta_foto FROM SPA_OFERTAS WHERE id_oferta = ?";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already do it!

Just need to change the `<a href` to (in my case...in your case you will need to change the url and the id of the data) because I now use a ajax modal:

```
<a href="spa_oferta.php?id_oferta='.$row["id_oferta"].'" data-toggle="modal" class="cp-btn"><span>CUP&Oacute;N</span></a>
```

and in the modal delete this part which is the beginning of the modal:

```
<div id="spaferta" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

and of course the close div in the end of the modal:

```
</div>
```